# Move point to current org heading

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode

In Org mode: How can I move point (up) to the current heading (or the first line under the heading)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is binding `C-c C-p` which might please you.

From the docstring: '`C-c C-p` runs the command org-previous-visible-heading'. Also note `C-c C-n` for the move to the next heading.

Answer (score 7):

`org-mode` is built on top of `outline-mode`, so you can use all the [outline navigation commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Motion.html#Outline-Motion).  The one most relevant to your question will be `outline-previous-visible-heading`.  You should probably find a comfortable keybinding if you plan to use it a lot.

Note that there is also a non-interactive `org-back-to-heading` that you could wrap in a command, if you like.  Docstring says:

> `(org-back-to-heading &optional INVISIBLE-OK)`
>
> Call `outline-back-to-heading`, but provide a better error message.