# Move point to previous/next parent heading

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode

[This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18896/5345) answer describes how to move point to the next or previous heading.

I would like to move point to the next or previous heading, which is one level higher up the tree (at the parent level).

For example:

```
* One
** OneA
** OneB []
** OneC
* Two
```

If point is the `[]`, I would like to move point to `* One` or `* Two` immediately.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`C-c C-u` runs the command `outline-up-heading`, which moves up to the parent heading. `C-c C-f` runs the command `org-forward-same-level` (or `org-forward-heading-same-level` as of org mode 9.1.9), which moves forward to the next heading at the same level. You can mix and match as you like to get what you need.

`C-c C-j` runs the command `org-goto`, which provides a general interface for quickly navigating through all headings.

This is explained in the [orgmode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Motion.html#Motion), along with other related commands.

Comment: Upvote for `org-forward-same-level`. I searched org functions for something like this starting with `org-next-` (similar to `org-next-visible-heading`).

Comment: I wish there were an `outline-down-heading`, for symmetry with `outline-up-heading`. As a result, going down to the next parent requires 2 commands (`outline-up-heading` then `org-forward-same-level`) instead of 1 (`outline-down-heading`).

Answer (score 11):

As [the other answer on that post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17054/253) points out, `org-mode` is built on top of `outline-mode`, so you have access to all of the [outline motion commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Motion.html#Outline-Motion).  According to the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Motion.html#Outline-Motion), you can use:

> `C-c C-f`
>   Move point to the next visible heading line at the same level as the one point is on (`outline-forward-same-level`).
>
> `C-c C-b`
>   Move point to the previous visible heading line at the same level (`outline-backward-same-level`).
>
> `C-c C-u`
>   Move point up to a lower-level (more inclusive) visible heading line (`outline-up-heading`).

Comment: However, C-c C-u moves to the next parent level. How about moving to the PREVIOUS parent level? :)

Answer (score -1):

On headline invoke the command `outline-hide-other` by pressing `M-x` outline-hide-other `RET`, unfortunately the standard key combo to invoke `C-c C-o` is rebound by org-mode